# GitHub API: Use pre-defined account for API

Tags: meteor, github, oauth, github-api, restful-url

I have an application where I need the server side code to create and delete repositories on my OWN GitHub account. GitHub API's OAuth authentication only works if I sign into GitHub on the client side. I need something that would allow me to store the username and password (or some sort of key) on the server side, therefore everything can work without any UI interaction whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can do the authentication from server to server, quoting from the github api:

> **OAuth2 Key/Secret**

```
curl "https://api.github.com/users/whatever?client_id=xxxx&client_secret=yyyy"
```

> This should only be used in server to server scenarios. Don't leak
>   your OAuth application's client secret to your users.

https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

The client id and secret can be either Meteor settings, or environment variables on the server (*Don't put them in your code!!*). As long as your server is secure, it should be safe.